# Having trouble with list post-processing

Tags: python, list, formatting

I have a small program in which post-processing is required on a Python list. These elements are part of the list:

```
Exit 14:07:11
Entry 14:07:16
Exit 14:07:20
Entry 14:07:24
Exit 14:07:28
Entry 14:07:32
Exit 14:07:36
Entry 14:07:40
Exit 14:07:44
```

Which is basically a reading of entering and exiting of a person in a room (only one door). So two entries or exits cannot be together. How can I get it in the form:

```
Entry....
Exit.....
Entry....
Exit.....
Entry....
Exit.....
Entry....
Exit ......
```

and so on? Here is what I tried, using a `for` loop, but this doesn't work:

```
 for i in range(0,len(y)-2):
        if y[i] == y[i+1]:
            y.remove(y[i])
    print y
    # close the cursor object
```

how can i get in the desired format?

Comment: What is `y` in your code?

Comment: Could you provide more information than *"this doesn't work"*, please

Comment: if there is a space, then you could use 'split' to create a tuple containing the Exit/Entry item and the next the time

Comment: @LutzHorn y is the list object

Comment: Then plesae [edit] your answer include the relevant code that defines `y`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  it meant that on deleting an item index of elements changes and soo above logic isnt working.

Comment: Do not modify an object, while iterating over it!

Comment: So **add that information to the question**, e.g. providing example inputs with expected and actual outputs.

Comment: @HardeosinghSingh given the example - are you just trying to reverse the entries?

Comment: @HardeosinghSingh I am assuming the list is in the format [ "Exit 14:07:11", "Entry 14:07:16", "Exit 14:07:20", "Entry 14:07:24", "Exit 14:07:28", "Entry 14:07:32", "Exit 14:07:36", "Entry 14:07:40", "Exit 14:07:44"]

Answer (score 0):

ok... so try this, the problem is you are deleting the elements while iterating, so try using list comprehension: -

```
y = [temp for i,temp in enumerate(y[:-1]) if y[i].split(" ")[0] !=y[i+1].split(" ")[0]] + [y[-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good thing to iterate over a list and remove its items at the same time.

Why not using another temporary list ?

```
tmpList = []
for ele in y : 
    # take last element of the list and compare it with the current one
    if len(tmpList) and tmpList[-1].split(" ")[0] == ele.split(" ")[0] : 
        continue
    tmpList.append(ele)

y = tmpList
```

Comment: how does this answers the question?